# What do I need to add the ribbon control in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ribbon

What do I need to add the ribbon control into Visual Studio? Is the Ribbon included in VS 2010?

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: free or cost?  Wpf or Winform(or Silverlight)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Ribbion Controls are added via a 3rd party control suite.

Some of the popular ones are

1. DevExpress [DevExpress XtraBars Suite](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Bars/)
2. DevComponents [DevComponents Ribbion Control](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/ribbon-control.aspx)
3. Telerik [Telerik RadRibbonBar](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/ribbonbar.aspx)
4. ComponentOne [Component One Ribbion Bar](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/RibbonWinForms/)

These are links to the WinForms controls most of the companies also have similar WPF versions of the control.

And Here is a link to a StackOverflow post about Free Controls
[SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361271/best-free-controls-for-net)

(I'm sure I didn't list all of the possible vendors)

Answer (score 4):

For a "Free" implementation see here --> 
http://windowsribbon.codeplex.com/

and here for a walkthrough on implementing it -->
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2009/12/23/windows-ribbon-for-winforms-part-0-table-of-contents.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can find a ribbon control at http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/ribbon-control.aspx
As I know, there isn't a ribbon control included in VS 2010 RC for WinForms

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [Ribbon Control Library DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx) is an option.  Click "License the Office UI" and follow the instructions from there.  Unfortunately, the ribbon control provided here does not show in designer view. but it does have all of the functionality of the Ribbon.

Here is a link to a sample project: http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/hands-on-labs/entry76491.aspx